# Visa requirements for Kuala Lumpur / Singapore

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, singapore, malaysia

I'm planning a two-week trip to Kuala Lumpur and Singapore and have a visa query. I'd appreciate insights on whether I should apply for a single-entry or multiple-entry visa for Kuala Lumpur. My itinerary includes the first 3 days in KL, the next week in Singapore, and finally another 3 days in KL. Any guidance on visa requirements and the application process would be valuable.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to share an update after visiting both Malaysia (ML) and Singapore (SG). Thankfully, we didn't require any visas, and there were no associated visa costs. However, we did need to complete the Malaysia Digital Arrival Card (MDAC) form online, which is short and should be submitted only before 3 days of your arrival.

We spent our first week in ML before traveling to SG for another week. Upon returning from SG to ML by bus, we were required to complete the MDAC form again.

Here's a learning experience for others: Our bus from SG departed at approximately 9:30 PM and arrived at the ML immigration department around 11:05 PM that same day (before midnight). While this meant entering ML on the same day, I had filled out the MDAC form with an expected arrival date for the following day. Essentially, I arrived in ML an hour earlier than stated on my form. The immigration officer requested the MDAC, but thankfully, he understood that we were a family and simply advised us not to repeat the mistake in the future before allowing us to enter.

I wanted to share this experience so others can avoid making the same mistake.

Comment: Thanks for returning to tell us how it went!

Comment: Note that free Malaysia visa for Indians is a temporary measure and can change.

Answer (score 2):

You're going twice to Malaysia. You'll need 2 separate visas, but there's a way to get two different ones.

1. From India to Malaysia. Apply before leaving for a Malaysian eNTRI.
2. From Singapore to Malaysia. Two ways: another eNTRI, if you're flying Singapore- KL; although you'll probably have to wait until you leave Malaysia to apply for it. Or a visa on arrival at Tuas – Sultan Abu Bakar Complex Second Link, if you're going back to KL by bus or otherwise not flying.

Or just revise your travel plans to make it one week each.

Comment: Isnt malesia visa free for Indians now?

Comment: @NitinKhubani You're right: temporary measure for a year that started December 1.